# Why my css isn't working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

So i'm building a web page using codeigniter framework, i have a simple page in which i use some css. I't works fine in all browsers except IE 7 (and possibly other versions of IE, I haven't checked yet).

The problem is i'm trying to display tabs and enable that it looks like it was selected on click.

my css is:

```
    .nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav-tabs:before,
.nav-tabs:after{
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.nav-tabs:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs > li{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a{
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
          border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

li.selected{
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  display:inline;
}
```

There are quite some problems in my ie, the list isn't displayed inline on hower isn't working at all, when i select an item nothing happens. Here is my file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab2'); ?>');
    document.getElementById("tab2").setAttribute("class", "selected");
});

function change_tab(a){
    //document.getElementById("tab1").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    document.getElementById("tab2").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    document.getElementById("tab3").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    document.getElementById("tab4").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    document.getElementById("tab5").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    document.getElementById("tab6").setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    if(a==1){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab1'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab1").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    else if(a==2){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab2'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab2").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    else if(a==3){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab3'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab3").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    else if(a==4){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab4'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab4").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    else if(a==5){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab5'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab5").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    else if(a==6){
        $("#content_of_tab").load('<?php echo site_url('console/show_tab6'); ?>');
        document.getElementById("tab6").setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
}
</script>

<div id="tabs" style="width: 976px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
    <!--    <li id="tab1" onclick="change_tab(1);"><a href="#">Pregled polic</a></li>  -->
        <li id="tab2" onclick="change_tab(2);"><a href="#">Prenos na drug EZŠO</a></li>
        <li id="tab3" onclick="change_tab(3);"><a href="#">Sprožitev osvežitve</a></li>
        <li id="tab4" onclick="change_tab(4);"><a href="#">Nadomeščenke</a></li>    
        <li id="tab5" onclick="change_tab(5);"><a href="#">Spremembe statusov</a></li>
        <li id="tab6" onclick="change_tab(6);"><a href="#">Sprememba zastopnika</a></li>

    </ul>
    </br>
    <div id="content_of_tab" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    </div>

</div>
```

This is only a file in which are the problems before that there is a header and footer view. In header i have set doctype as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I have a lot of css on other files and there is working so there must be problem in that.

I apriciate all ideas!

EDIT: printscreen of difrencies

http://shrani.si/f/1T/zp/1oru9l8h/diffrence.png

left is list in firefox and right is in ie.

I just installed IE9 and it's steel not working the look is the same as in IE7...

Comment: "Except IE" is a little bit too general. Please specify which version of Internet Explorer you're using. Also a screenshot which shows the difference could help.

Comment: have you tryied adding display: inline and float: left on the tabs tag?

Comment: You didn't mention the version of IE. It might work on IE8 and later but won't work on IE6 and IE7 because the CSS is not compatible to them.

Comment: Well i'm using IE7 but i'm sure it's not working on IE8, u will get screens in a sec.

Comment: IE7 and down don't support `:before` http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Comment: How do you know it's not working in IE8 if you haven't tried it?

Comment: This is a web page on internet with limited access and other users reported that to me ...

Comment: As an addition to what Andy has stated IE7 wont support `display:table` either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` triggers Quirks Modes in browsers. This makes them inconsistent with the standards and each other as they emulate bugs in older browsers.

The correct Doctype to use for HTML 4.01 Transitional is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Once you have this in place, make sure that your HTML and CSS are both [valid](http://validator.w3.org).

> `document.getElementById("tab4").setAttribute("class", "selected");`

`setAttribute` is broken in older versions of Internet Explorer. Avoid it. Since you are already using jQuery I recommend using its `addClass` method instead. Alternatively set the `className` property directly.

Comment: Thank u very much! The problem was in doctype!